# MySQL - Search in date records

Tags: mysql, date, datetime

I am trying to make an SQL for the situation bellow and I have no success. I am
also not sure how to search for this solution in google.

**Table "account Manager log"**

```
Date                    user_id
2014-10-14 19:12:29     51
2014-11-03 14:46:21     39
2015-08-19 11:20:15     2
2015-09-24 09:21:41     15
```

So, in 14-oct-2014, the account manager was user #51. In 03-Nov-2014, the account was transfered from 51 to 39.

> I need to make an SQL which will return me who is the account mananger
>   in a given datetime. For example: Who is the account manager on
>   05-JAN-2015 14:00? Answer is user_id = 2.

Could some one point me in the right direction please?
Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the answer actually be 39?

Comment: Could you give an example of a query you tried that isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution is to select all records where the date is less than the one you want, sort them in descending order, and limit it to 1 record :)

```
SELECT * FROM "account Manager log" WHERE date <= '03/19/2014'  ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: LIMIT needs to go after ORDER BY

Comment: @Mike Thanks - it's been a while.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the account manager on 1/5/2015 is actually user_id 39.  Here's one option to achieve that using `limit`:

```
select user_id
from yourtable
where date <= '2015-01-05'
order by date desc
limit 1
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/07943b/2)